# Using Dataframe to Automatically create a list of values based off Subproduct

Tags: r, list, dataframe, time-series, data-manipulation

```
df <- data.frame("date"= 
1:4,"product"=c("B","B","A","A"),"subproduct"=c("1","2","x","y"),"actuals"=1:4)


#creates df1,df2,dfx,dfy
for(i in unique(df$subproduct)) {
  nam <- paste("df", i, sep = ".")
  assign(nam, df[df$subproduct==i,])

}

# CREATES LIST OF DATAFRAMES
# How do I make this so i don't have to manually type list(df.,df.,df.)

list_df <- list(df.1,df.2,df.x,df.y) %>%
  lapply( function(x) x[(names(x) %in% c("date", "actuals"))])

# creates df1,df2,df3,df4 only dates and actuals, removes the other column names
for (i in 1:length(list_df)) {
  assign(paste0("df", i), as.data.frame(list_df[[i]]))
}
```

For the first for loop, it creates a df object based off unique subproduct. For the list() function, I want to be able to not have to type in df.1 ... df2... etc so if I have 100 unique subproducts in my data, I wouldn't need to type this df.1, df.2,df.x,df.y,df.z,df.zzz,df. over and over again. How would I best do this (1 question)

The last for loop creates separate dataframe objects with only date and actuals will be used to create time series for each. How can I put the values of these objects into a single dataframe or a list of dfs? (2nd question)

Comment: are you trying to do `split(df[1:2], df[3])`??

Comment: The first loop creates dataframes based off unique subproducts, so 4 new dfs in this case. I want to eventually add 20+ columns to each new DF, so putting it into a list of df's is what I want to do. The list_df line is a manually implementation, but I want to make it so I don't need to type out each unique df's name.

Comment: You do not need any for-loops here. It seems you are splitting your data, just as the code I provided does.

Comment: Hmm you are right, this could work. I will play around with it. Will update later

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can use `mget` to return the value of object on the subset of object names from `ls`.  The `pattern` matches object names that starts with 'df'`followed by a`.` and any alphanumeric characters

```
mget(ls(pattern = '^df\\.[[:alnum:]]+$'))
```

If the OP wanted to create those objects in a different env

```
new_env <- new.env()
list2env(mget(ls(pattern = '^df\\.[[:alnum:]]+$')), envir = new_env)
```

---

If we want to create new objects from scratch, do a `group_split` on the 'subproduct' column, set the names accordingly, and create multiple objects (`list2env` - not recommended though)

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)
df %>% 
   group_split(subproduct) %>%
   setNames(str_c('df.', c(1, 2, 'x', 'y'))) %>% 
   list2env(.GlobalEnv)
```

Comment: Wow I never knew I could do something like this. Df.1,df.2 etc will have 20+ columns added to each and then inner joined and exported later. Is there anyway I can create a list of these objects in my environment as I can modify them as needed later?

Comment: @chriswang123 these objects are already in your enviornment, which is the reason why the `mget` works

Comment: @chriswang123 Are you saying that you have a different env than the global env

Comment: @chriswang123 i am not sure if the update is what you wanted. please check

Comment: Sorry if I'm not explaining things well. Basically say I have df.1,df.2 etc. I eventually will add values to each separate df. For example ... df.1$arima <- c(1,2,3,5) and the same for df.2$arima... etc etc. I want them into list of dfs, hence my list_df code. I want an easier way to create my list_df, instead of manually typing list( and all of my dfs names)

Comment: Wow this is amazing. Is there anyway  to automatically create the variable names and put all of the df objects into one list? Say I had 100 unique subproducts, typing out the new names would be time consuming.

Comment: @chriswang123 it is a single list `df %>% 
   group_split(subproduct) %>%
   setNames(str_c('df.', c(1, 2, 'x', 'y')))`  I added the `list2env` in case if you want to create multiple objects

Comment: Ok I see now. If I wanted to add new columns to each df in the list, how would I go about doing that? If i do df[[1]]$newcol <- 1, it gives me an error

Comment: @chriswang123 what columns you want to add.  Then do `df %>%     group_split(subproduct) %>%    setNames(str_c('df.', c(1, 2, 'x', 'y'))) %>% map(~ .x %>% mutate(newcol = 1))`